# Newbie question: why is the end result changing?

Tags: c++, cout

I am almost completely new to C++ and I am trying to write something that finds the approximation of pi based on a formula.
The formula is not important but when I try to run the code, it gets different results for no reason(?)
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

double pie (int N){
    double s;
    double x;
    for (int i=1; i<=N; i++){
    s = s + 1/(1+pow((i-0.5)/N,2));
}
    x = s*4/N;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int Nmin = 1;
    while(pie(Nmin) > 3.15){
         Nmin++;
         cout<<Nmin<<endl;
    }
        cout<<pie(Nmin)<<" "<< pie(Nmin)<<" "<< pie(Nmin)<<endl;
        cout<<pie(Nmin)<<" <-- correct one"<<endl;
}
```

[Run on VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqqC2.png)

[Run on Onlinegdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLfVF.png)

As shown in the picture, the results after running the code are weirdly different from each other. And I just cannot figure out what is causing it.

Thank you for reading, any help is appreciated.

Comment: the formula is all that is important here. You are using `s` before it is initialized, which causes undefined behavior. Output can be anything

Comment: E.g. you want consistency and defined behavior, `double s = 0.;`

Comment: rule of thumb: Always initialize variables. In different words: Only declare a variable when you can initialize it. `double s;` is a code smell

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the variable 's' before using it.

Please initialize the variable as `double s = 0;`